# serve static files in microservice

Tags: microservices, nestjs, static-files

I'm trying to serve static files, an image in my case, in my nestjs microservice.
Has anyone an idea of how to do that?
The only information I can find is how to serve static files in normal nestjs applications, but not how to with a microservice application.

Answer (score 2):

from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static)

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client'),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: That doesn't work since I want to use it in an microservice and it doens't have an api

Answer (score 0):

Oke I fixed it to serve the image in the 'main-service' which is an api that connects to the microservices.
Used the example above and the docs to do it.